# Select Item in NSCollectionView on mouseDown, not mouseUp?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview

I'd like to make it so my NSCollectionView's selection behavior matches the  icon-view in Finder. Finder will select and highlight elements when the mouse button is clicked down, but NSCollectionView's built in behavior appears to use mouse up to trigger a selection.

Is there a way to make NSCollectionView act like Finder in this regard?

Comment: If your goal is just to provide visual feedback, have you looked into the ```NSCollectionViewItem.highlightState``` property? Namely the ```forSelection``` case?

Comment: Hmm yes, that works...

I didn't know the highlight state would get set to "forSelection" before the  selection actually took place. Thank you!

Added the following code:

   `override var highlightState: NSCollectionViewItemHighlightState{

        didSet{

            if highlightState == .forSelection{

                self.showSelectedHighlight()

            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per pfandtrade's comment above, it looks like the highlight state of an NSCollectionViewItem will be changed before that item is selected.

mouseDown = NSCollectionViewItem's highlightState is set to forSelection

mouseUp = NSCOllectionViewItem's highlightState is set to none, but isSelected property is then set to true.

I added the following to my NSCollectionViewItem subclass:

```
override var highlightState: NSCollectionViewItemHighlightState{
    didSet{
        if self.highlightState == .forSelection{
            self.showSelectedHighlight() //my stylization function
        }
    }
}
```